# Wireless broadband connnection Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, 13.04, internet

For some reasons, I cannot connect to internet on wifi, but I can connect to wireless broadband on Windows, but I don't know how to set it up in Ubuntu 13.04.

My connection is a DSL cable that I have plugged in the wifi router. I have a username and a passoword.

On Windows, I could connect easily as it automatically recognized the Broadband connection on my wifi. But I don't know how to set it up on Ubuntu.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

some times ubuntu initially drivers will not work so,you need to update your drivers to work wifi in ubuntu , so initially connect pc/laptop with "cable" and it automatically detect your internet connection.

After that you can update the drivers then restart the pc , unplug the cable and now you can search your wifi and give password for connection.

For any query , please add comment.